# Generalization of Kakutani-Ky Fan Theorem without convexity assumptions

Tags: convex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I'm wondering if there exists some extension of the Kakutani-Ky Fan Theorem

> **Theorem.**  *Let $K$ be a nonempty, compact and convex subset of a locally convex space $X$. Let $f:K\longrightarrow 2^K$ be upper semicontinuous, such that $f(x)$ is nonempty, convex and closed for every $x\in K$. Then f has a fixed point $\bar x\in K$.*

maybe without the convexity assumption of $f(x)$, or with some assumption such that $f(x)$ is homeomorphic to a convex set. I did some research in literature but, except some old articles (e.g. *I. L. Glicksberg, A Further Generalization of the Kakutani Fixed Point Theorem, with Application to Nash Equilibrium Points* and *J-P. Penot, Fixed point theorems without convexity*) which do not suit me anyway, i didn't find anything.

May you suggest me, if there are, some books or articles where I can find a similar result?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counter-example to show that convexity of $f$ is necessary. Let $C$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$, let $K$ be the closed ball of radius $2$ in $\mathbb R^2$. Define $f(x) = (x + C)\cap K$. Then $x\not\in f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was wondering if such hypothesis could be replaced by some assumption such that the image $f(x)$ is homeomorphic to a convex set. May you suggest me something?

Comment: Maybe we can make a small gap into $C$?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Take just a segment of the circle.